How in facade wrapper to make 1 one app bind calling?
On laravel site I defined a facade based on LoggedUserService with Interface class, whicj looks like :
<?php

namespace App\Library\Facades;

use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\LoggedUserInterface;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class LoggedUserFacade
{
    public static function getAvatarHtml(?string $customClass = '', bool $showPermissions = false): string
    {
        $loggedUserInterface = app(LoggedUserInterface::class);
        return $loggedUserInterface->getAvatarHtml(customClass: $customClass, showPermissions: $showPermissions);
    }

    public static function checkUserLogged(): string
    {
        $loggedUserInterface = app(LoggedUserInterface::class);
        return $loggedUserInterface->checkUserLogged();
    }

    public static function getLoggedUser(): Authenticatable|null
    {
        $loggedUserInterface = app(LoggedUserInterface::class);
        return $loggedUserInterface->getLoggedUser();
    }


}

I defined several public static functions and wonder if there is a way to make one app bind calling, not in any static method I have above ?
"laravel/framework": "^10.48.7",
"php": "8.2",

Thanks in advance!
Attempt To Fix :
No, I got error :
Constant expression contains invalid operations

with such declaration.
I tried to init in __construct method :
class LoggedUserFacade
{
    private static $loggedUserInterface;

    public function __construct()
    {
//        die("IF UCOMMENTED - IS NOT CALLED");
        self::$loggedUserInterface = app(LoggedUserInterface::class);
    }

    public static function getAvatarHtml(?string $customClass = '', bool $showPermissions = false): string
    {
        return self::$loggedUserInterface->getAvatarHtml(customClass: $customClass, showPermissions: $showPermissions);
    }

But this __construct method  is not called...

You can actually implement your own facade using a Laravel's facade
namespace App\Library\Facades;

use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\LoggedUserInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;


class LoggedUserFacade extends Facade {
   protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
       return LoggedUserInterface::class;
   }
}

You can then use the facade by just using method names defined in LoggedUserInterface e.g.
   LoggedUserFacade::checkUserLogged();

Laravel will handle injecting the interface as a singleton based on how you've bound it in the DI container.

You can use a facade like this :
<?php

namespace App\Library\Facades;

use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\LoggedUserInterface;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class LoggedUserFacade extends Facade
{
    
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'logged-user-service'; }

}

You have to create a service provider LoggedUserServiceProvider.php :
class LoggedUserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('logged-user-service', function()
        {
            return new LoggedUserService;
        });
    }
}

Assuming that the service that implement LoggedUserInterface is LoggedUserService.
And don't forget to register your service provider :
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
    // Other Service Providers

    App\Providers\LoggedUserServiceProvider::class,
])->toArray(),

For the usage you simply do it like this :
LoggedUserFacade::getAvatarHtml($customClass, $showPermissions);
LoggedUserFacade::checkUserLogged();
LoggedUserFacade::getLoggedUser();


Please take a look at Attempt To Fix

Follow this code and change these lines:
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        // Bind the LoggedUserInterface to its concrete implementation
        $this->app->bind(LoggedUserInterface::class, LoggedUserService::class);
    }

}

// LoggedUserFacade.php   ;

class LoggedUserFacade extends Facade
{
    // Specify what service container binding to resolve
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return LoggedUserInterface::class;
    }
}   


Code-only answers are not good answers. Please explain how this would solve the issue at hand
